# Finding distinct pair count with criteria excell / google spredsheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a data set like this in Google Sheet (Excel is fine too):

```
A B
----
1 blue
1 blue
1 blue
1 red
2 blue
2 red
3 blue
3 blue
```

I would like to count the number of distinct pairs based on a criteria in column D. and get a result like this:

```
C D
----
3 blue 
2 red
```

So, I need a function that will look at all column A and B pairs and count those pairs that contain the value in column D and place the count in column C.

I **can't use** a Pivot table.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the column **D** where there is ("blue" and "red") you need to use a formula like :

```
unique(filter(B:B,B:B<>""))
```

For the column **C** where you have the corresponding result (3 and 2) you need to use on each row a formula like this:

```
=counta(unique((filter($A:$A,$B:$B=$D1))))
```

where in `$D1` 1 is the number of the row corresponding to the name in column **C**

Answer (score 1):

@Harold's is the easiest way to do it in Google Sheets.

I had a slight variation on the formula which was:-

```
=countunique(filter($A$1:$A$8,$B$1:$B$8=D1))
```

For the record, this is probably the easiest way to do it in Excel if there aren't too many rows:-

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B$1:B$8=D1)/COUNTIFS(A$1:A$8,A$1:A$8,B$1:B$8,B$1:B$8))
```

and this works in Excel and Google Sheets:-

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(B$1:B$8=D1,A$1:A$8),A$1:A$8)>0))
```

if entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets has COUNTUNIQUE which makes it easy.

```
=COUNTUNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,B:B=D1))
```